# How to fire event on Unity after an interstitial ad close?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, admob

I'm using the last AdMob plugin into Unity3d.

I know there are these kind of requests for AdMob:

```
// Called when an ad request has successfully loaded.
bannerView.AdLoaded += HandleAdLoaded;

// Called when an ad request failed to load.
bannerView.AdFailedToLoad += HandleAdFailedToLoad;

// Called when an ad is clicked.
bannerView.AdOpened += HandleAdOpened;

// Called when the user is about to return to the app after an ad click.
bannerView.AdClosing += HandleAdClosing;

// Called when the user returned from the app after an ad click.
bannerView.AdClosed += HandleAdClosed;

// Called when the ad click caused the user to leave the application.
bannerView.AdLeftApplication += HandleAdLeftApplication;
```

But I need to fire an event after the user clicked the (X) button to close the interstitial Ad. How should I do that?

The ad loads after the level is finished, than I want to load the next level with "Application.LoadLevel(something)".

I've been trying to do this for hours, thanks

Comment: Do whatever you need to do inside HandleAdClosed or HandleAdClosing

Answer (score 0):

the .AdClosed worked just right after I figured out what was wrong.

You have to use:

```
using System;
```

or EventArgs wont work